# For Loop of Datatable.rows breaks while exporting Datatable to excel in C# .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am trying to export data from `Datatable to Excel`. The Datatable has `8540 rows` and `31 columns`.

**The loop below breaks somewhere after 3500 records:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < Tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Tbl.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
         workSheet.Cells[(i + 2), (j + 1)] = Tbl.Rows[i][j];
    }
}
```

Is there any limit of rows while exporting? or something else I am doing wrong? Please Help!

The code I am using for export is:

```
public static void ExportExcel(this DataTable Tbl, string ExcelFilePath = null)
{
    try
    {
        if (Tbl == null || Tbl.Columns.Count == 0)
            //throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Null or empty input table!\n");
            Console.WriteLine("ExportToExcel: Null or empty input table!\n");

        // load excel, and create a new workbook
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

        // single worksheet
        Excel._Worksheet workSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

        // column headings
        for (int i = 0; i < Tbl.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            workSheet.Cells[1, (i + 1)] = Tbl.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            workSheet.Cells[1, (i + 1)].Font.Bold = true;
            workSheet.Cells[1, (i + 1)].Font.Size = 12;
        }

        // rows
        for (int i = 0; i < Tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            // to do: format datetime values before printing
            for (int j = 0; j < Tbl.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                workSheet.Cells[(i + 2), (j + 1)] = Tbl.Rows[i][j];
            }
        }

        // check fielpath
        if (ExcelFilePath != null && ExcelFilePath != "")
        {
            try
            {
                workSheet.SaveAs(ExcelFilePath);
                excelApp.Quit();
                //MessageBox.Show("Excel file saved!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath.\n"+ ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("ExportToExcel: Excel file could not be saved! Check filepath.\n"+ ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else    // no filepath is given
        {
            excelApp.Visible = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: \n" + ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine("ExportToExcel: \n" + ex.Message); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean on "breaks"? What happens? Do you get an exception? If yes please post the exception message!

Comment: Ok, but *how* does it break?

Comment: I don't get any exception... this i got when I debugged the code... It just simply stops execution...

Comment: @aks Stops execution? just it exits from the loop? check the count of table rows.

Comment: @EhsanUllah ya it just stops and exit from loop also it doesn't goes to next if statement... `Tbl.Rows.Count=8540` and `Tbl.Columns.Count=31` ... it stops somewhere after `i=3500 `

Comment: you have tagget your sample with asp.net mvc. i hope you don't use office automation in mvc apps.

Comment: system might be going out of memory. Please monitor memory.

Answer (score 0):

If I might offer an alternative: Use **EPPLUS** and its great *LoadFromDataTable** Function - this would reduce your code to one line, it is magnitudes faster and it does not rely on Excel directly.
Also: the library is free and can be included without licensing problems.

Comment: Seems like not a direct answer. How about posting this as a comment rather than an answer?

Comment: I wanted to solve his Problem rather than fixing his actual code. This was based on the assumption that his solution has lots of problems and should be dropped altogether.